# I want XML::Twig to print exactly what was parsed in

Tags: xml, perl, xml-twig

I have XML that contains &apos; for ', etc.  When I parse it in using XML::Twig and then print it out again, all the &apos; are printed as '.  Also, XML::Twig seems to reorder attributes to put them in alphabetical order.  From the point of view of XML, these are equivalent, but, I want to make a small set of changes to XML and use diff to confirm the only changes made are the ones I intended.  Is there a way to get XML::Twig to change nothing except what I explicitly change?

Here's my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<System>
  <P C="C" B="B" A="A">&apos;&lt;&gt;&quot;&amp;</P>
  <P A="A" B="B" C="C">'&lt;>"&amp;</P>
</System>
```

And the perl:

```
my $twig = new XML::Twig(KeepSpaces => 'true');
$twig->parsefile("test.xml");
$twig->print();
```

And here's what gets printed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<System>
  <P A="A" B="B" C="C">'&lt;>"&amp;</P>
  <P A="A" B="B" C="C">'&lt;>"&amp;</P>
</System>
```

Comment: What about "unifying" both the original and the output before comparing? We use `xmllint --c14n FILE.XML | xmllint --format -` for both and then the standard `diff`.

Comment: That's a thought.  I'd still prefer to not have to normalize the XML to do the diff, but this could be a reasonable fallback.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like the [`keep_encoding`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aTwig#keep_encoding) option does the trick:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new( 
                    keep_spaces     => 1, 
                    keep_encoding   => 1, 
                    keep_atts_order => 1,
);
$twig->parsefile('test.xml');
$twig->print;
```

Update: Improved in response to mirod's comment.

Comment: also `keep_atts_order => 1`

Comment: and if you know which elements you want to change you can use `twig_roots => { elt => sub { change_elt( $_); $_->flush } }, twig_print_outside_roots => 1`